# JavaScript code in view or template files

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, laravel, dom

I have a question about writing small chunks of JavaScript code in any CMS or framework view/template files. i.e, WordPress template files or Laravel blade files

Take for example Laravel's blade files.

I am writing small JS chunks in `view1.blade.php` & `view2.blade.php`

More specifically jQuery code that is wrapped in a DOM ready event listener:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    some_func($);

});

function some_func($) {

    $('body').addClass('some-class');

}
```

I know the right way should be to add all the JS code in an external JS file. i.e, `scripts.js`

But the other way is more convenient for me to work with.

My question is does it affect the site performance? I don't see that happening because all my JS code in the views are wrapped in a DOM ready event listener. Neither it is blocking the DOM render. Thanks

Comment: Any effect on site performance is minimal. The larger effect will be on the bandwidth used, as spreading your JS code around the project will mean it can't be minified, or easily cached in a single URL, but again that's minimal. The bigger problem is simply maintainability. You should follow the Separation of Concerns principle so you, or anyone unlucky enough to work on the project after you, knows exactly where all the relevant code is, and what needs to be changed and doesn't waste time searching for it. The pattern you're using right now would be unacceptable in any team project.

Comment: Exactly. That is why I am writing small JS code inside the view/template files. Another reason is I am breaking down the view/template/partial files into easily understandable folders.

Of course if the JS code is larger than I am putting them in an external JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@stack('scripts')` to your common template. Like Main Template layout.

For pushing code into this, use:

```
@push('scripts')
<script>Your code</script>
@endpush
```

Another way is `@yield('script')` in common template where you want to include scripts and add code on individual blade within:

```
@section('script')
<script>Your code</script>
@endsection
```